# How to generate a time string for jsonschema

Tags: javascript, python, jsonschema

I have a schema like this:

```
"foo": {"type": "string", "format": "time"}
```

I tried `new (new Date()).toISOString()` it has this format:

```
"2018-06-12T08:59:01.135Z"
```

**Error:**

```
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: '2018-06-12T08:59:01.135Z' is not a 'time'
```

Comment: Try doing it without converting to string

Comment: Try to do it without converting to iso string

Comment: neither work...

Comment: The "time" format must only include the time, not the date. To include date and time, use "date-time".  See http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.7.3.1

Answer (score 1):

`{ "format": "time" }` uses RFC-3339 section-5.6 "Internet Date/Time Format".

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.7.3.1
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your date `toJSON()`

```
new Date().toJSON()
```

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON)